# How can i select TitledPane`s title without CSS in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx

How can i select TitledPane`s title in Java Code, without CSS?

I made TitledPane and want to make the title`s font weight is bold.

So i tried like this.

```
TitledPane Rootpane = new TitledPane();
Rootpane.setText("Options");
Rootpane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #eeeeee; -fx-text-fill: #1b75bc; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
```

and the title became bold but the other buttons which are located in TitledPane also became bold...

I just want to make Title is bold without CSS file.

So how can i select the title in Java Code?

And i tried like this

```
Rootpane.lookup(".titled-pane > .title").setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
```

But the result was

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the `lookup()` after the node was added to the stage and after `Stage.show()`. For example like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TitledPane root = new TitledPane();
    root.setText("Options");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 100));
    primaryStage.show();

    root.lookup(".titled-pane > .title > .text").setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
}
```

As you can see you should also use `.titled-pane > .title > .text` to get the actual text label ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#titledpane)).

Comment: You might want to mention the significance of calling `lookup` after `primaryStage.show()`.